# Creating rows from related columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big wide table that stores id of people with their family information, like a pedigree (more than 20 columns that have id for a given person and his/her parents and parents of parents). All the data of a given person is available on a single row.

I want to create another table that has an entry for each individual from this original table. So in this table (target) I have every person as a separate entry in my table with just their mom's and dad's id (total of three columns).

In summary, the new table would be `id, momid, dadid` for each individual in the original table. So given id 1 his mom (2) should become a new Row in the target table, with their corresponding mom's and dad's (`momofmomid` and `dadofmomid`; 4 and 5).

Here is an image that represents the original table and what I need.

---

[image: Table]

Comment: You mean you essentially want a new table with just some columns from the original table ? Creating a new view with those columns would suffice.

Comment: Yes I need a new table with some columns from the original table.

Comment: Oh wait, so you mean each (momId,momOfMomId,dadOfMomId) etc would make a new tuple in the new table ? wow. That is not really apparent from the question. Please modify.

Comment: Thanks, modified the question by giving clear example in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by momId, dadId) as ID,
       momId, 
       dadId
       into newTable
  FROM (
        SELECT distinct momId, dadId 
          FROM (
                SELECT momId, dadId 
                  FROM actualTable
                UNION 
                SELECT momOfMomId, dadOfDadId
                  FROM actualTable
               ) tb
        ) tb2
```

Where `newTable` is the name of the new table that you want to create.

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31859/1

Edited the answer as OP explained in the comments what he really needed.
Also, I've made new IDs, so if it is not right, please explain how the ID for the new table should be processed.

**EDIT**

After understand the OP problem and having some more thought on it I actually figured it out that it was way simplier than I was thinking. So, here is the new solution:

```
SELECT id, momId, dadId INTO newTable2
  FROM (SELECT id, momId, dadId 
          FROM actualTable
        UNION 
        SELECT momId, momOfMomId, dadOfDadId
          FROM actualTable
       ) a;
```

This select will create the `newTable2`, if you don't need a new table just remove the `INTO newTable2` clause from the above query. To see the data in the new table just do:

```
SELECT * FROM newTable2
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b585b/1

Comment: But what about other columns. I need momid become a new id in the new table with her mom and dad id next to it. So I thought I might need to do a select like yours but for each of the related ids and union them all together. I wasn't sure if that would be the solution. And the problem would be the duplicates that will be added. In my example 2 is already in the new table so I am not adding it later. Hope this make sense.

Comment: Ooooh, I see your problem now, did not get it from jsut your sample. You will have to inform on your question all fields that you want to be added in the new table AS ROWS. Something like: `the target table will have for each row the momId from momId and also MomOfmomId as a new row` and also as with the dadId columns. Right now I think everyone understanded the same as I did. Please edit your question.

Comment: Also, explain the ID for the new table. It should be exactly as you added or it should be sequential?

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I don't have my table to check the solution but reading through it I think it is what I want. The id should be exactly as I have in the original table.

Comment: Jorge it looks good the only thing is that the given id should have corresponding momid and dadid. So mom of id 1, which is 2, should have 4 and 5 in the same row.

Comment: @Afi that will be a little more complicated. I will take a look tomorrow its late here at my end.

Comment: I am still struggling in this one could you guide me what approach should I take. I could make it via cursors but that is my last shot if nothing can't be done to do it in set operations. Thanks

Comment: @Afi I did not understand why the id of the new row must be the id of the momId (if it is the corresponding row of the momOfMomId for the first row). Thats make no sense. Can you axplain that in more details? I mean the first row of the result is 1,2,3 the second row is 2,4,5 see, the id of the second row is the same of the momId of the first one, then for the third row you want the id of the second row on the original table which is 6 and then following the same pattern. Add your image back on your question and try to explain this better on it. I'm saying the it makes no sense because of...

Comment: @Afi the data confiability. the new data should have a new pattern or at least have some kind of relationship on it. the result you want does not present any of then. It is late here again and tomorrow I will be in a conference all day, but I will be home late night and if you explain those questions I will do my best trying to help you out.

Comment: @Afi Heeeeyyy I actually figure it out and turns out that it is WAY simplier than I thought. Look at my Edit.

Comment: thanks a lot! this is exactly what I needed. I tried to up-vote it but don't have enough points to do it. Thanks again for figuring it out with my poor descriptions.

Comment: @Ai great! If you think that it is right you should accept it. Its the V button down the up/down vote button!!